# Get values from a tuple in a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = Bookshop()
x.orders = [ [1, ("5464", 4, 9.99), ("8274",18,12.99), ("9744", 9, 44.95)],
[2, ("5464", 9, 9.99), ("9744", 9, 44.95)],
[3, ("5464", 9, 9.99), ("88112", 11, 24.99)],
[4, ("8732", 7, 11.99), ("7733", 11,18.99), ("88112", 5, 39.95)] ]

r1 = x.prodcut_price()
print(r1)

class Bookshop:

    def __init__(self):
        self.orders = 0
    def prodcut_price(self):
        result1  = list(map(lambda x:(x[1][0],x[1][1]*x[1][2]) if x[1][1]*x[1][2]>=100 else (x[1][0],x[1][1]*x[1][2]+10),self.orders))
        #print(result1)
        return result1
```

The list is basically the store number and each store sell some books with the code, quantity and the price.I am trying to create a method that will take each book quantity * price and print them in a tuple within list using lambda,filter and map only. what I got is that

[('5464', 39.96), ('5464', 89.91), ('5464', 89.91), ('8732', 83.93)]

but I need it for the whole list

Answer (score 0):

To get those totals for a specific code you can do:

#### Code:

```
def get_value(orders_list, code):
    return {order[0]: o[1] * o[2] for order in orders_list
            for o in order[1:] if o[0] == code}
```

#### Test Data:

```
orders = [
    [1, ("5464", 4, 9.99), ("8274", 18, 12.99), ("9744", 9, 44.95)],
    [2, ("5464", 9, 9.99), ("9744", 9, 44.95)],
    [3, ("5464", 9, 9.99), ("88112", 11, 24.99)],
    [4, ("8732", 7, 11.99), ("7733", 11, 18.99), ("88112", 5, 39.95)]
]

print(get_value(orders, '5464'))
```

#### Results:

```
{1: 39.96, 2: 89.91, 3: 89.91}
```

Comment: I have to use filter, map, lambda only I can't use any other loops or function it is a requirement