# using filter to add similar values for a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list

```
order = [('5464', 39.96), ('8274', 233.82), ('9744', 404.55), 
         ('5464', 89.91), ('9744', 404.55), ('5464', 89.91), 
         ('88112', 274.89), ('8732', 83.93), ('7733', 208.89), ('88112', 199.75)]
```

and it is basically a list of book order number and the total about. I want t use filter, map, lambda, and reduce only to get a list of tuples that will add the values of the similar book order number so it will return a list of 7 tuples.

Comment: You are very welcome to do what you want, as long as it's legal. But what;s your question? (The one that ends with a question mark.)

Comment: how can I do that. SO for example '5464' is in the list 3 times so I want at the end to be [ ('5464', 219)] and so on for the rest of the elements

Comment: Why do you want to use those particular four functions?

Comment: part of my assignment, I have to use those functions in particular

Comment: Good. Now, how much have you done yourself and where is your code? Sadly, SO is not a code-writing service. We will not write code for you, but gladly answer any _specific_ questions related to the code that you posted.

Comment: I got this so far but it returns an error: r5 = list(map(lambda x: list(filter(lambda y: (y[1]+y[1]) if y[0] in y, x)),order))

Comment: Please incorporate the code, accurately formatted, into your question; and tell as what you think is wrong with it.

Comment: Well it wasn't exactly clear until the comment that it was required to use those functions. Typically a lot of questions go off on tangents trying to solve a problem in one way, when there are other tools available that simplify things. And aren't there only 6 unique book order numbers?

Comment: well yeah I know there is an easy way to do it but it is a part of what I have to do and yes there is 6 different order number and I need to add the total number for each one .\

Comment: You should not ask the same question again, especially if you already got an answer to it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49442335/get-values-from-a-tuple-in-a-list-in-python

Comment: it is not the same question it is the same project but not same question read both question carefully and you will figure it out

Answer (score 0):

This is the best i could do ,although there might be better ways to do it,perhaps the best way is to use a dictionary  , i hope this helps anyways

```
print(list(set(map(lambda x: (x[0],sum(map(lambda y:   y[1] if x[0] == y[0] else 0,order) )),order)) ) )
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[('9744', 809.1), ('88112', 474.64), ('5464', 219.78), ('8274', 233.82), ('8732', 83.93), ('7733', 208.89)]
```

Comment: In general, you should avoid doing someone else's homework assignments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try itertools with lambda :

```
import itertools

order = [('5464', 39.96), ('8274', 233.82), ('9744', 404.55),
         ('5464', 89.91), ('9744', 404.55), ('5464', 89.91),
         ('88112', 274.89), ('8732', 83.93), ('7733', 208.89), ('88112', 199.75)]


print(list(map(lambda m:(m[0],sum(map(lambda xa:xa[1],m[1]))),itertools.groupby(sorted(order),key=lambda x:x[0]))))
```

output:

```
[('5464', 219.78), ('7733', 208.89), ('8274', 233.82), ('8732', 83.93), ('88112', 474.64), ('9744', 809.1)]
```

If you want to use reduce function then :

```
print(list(map(lambda x:(x[0],functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,list(map(lambda x:x[1],list(x[1]))))),itertools.groupby(sorted(order),key=lambda x:x[0]))))
```